# How can I use Castle Windsor 4.1.1. to provide dependency in my ASP.NET Core MVC project for my controller?

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, castle-windsor

I have created an ASP.NET MVC project Visual Studio 2017 using the Framework .NET Core 2.1. I am new to Visual Studio 2017, how to import references, and Castle Windsor dependency injection so my issues may be quite basic. My ultimate goal is to use Castle Windsor dependency injection to specify my controller associated with an Entity Framework class. I have functional code without Castle Windsor but I'm trying to learn and specifically use Castle Windsor here.

I have looked at several articles for Castle Windsor such as 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-implement-castle-windsor-dependency-injection-in-mvc. However this example is using MVC4. I currently have a custom `DbContext` to provide access to my test objects.

My web page can already resolve the controller I believe by my MapRoute statement which was created automatically in the creation of my controller class.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=TestEntities}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

How can I incorporate Castle Windsor Dependency injection into this scenario?  Do I need to change my route definition?

As per a tutorial https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-part-2-plugging-windsor-in.md

I tried to create a WindsorControllerFactory to presumably resolve my controller.

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
        RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format(
                "The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.",
                requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }
        return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

With VS2017, I seemed to be unable to use the System.Web.Routing namespace in my project even when I added .NET Framework 4.0 version as an assembly reference. This means that I am unable to resolve the RequestContext class. Am I taking the wrong path here? I can't see where the missing Routing namespace is an issue for others.

I would appreciate any inputs or good reference links for this scenario.

Comment: Did you read [this part of the Castle Windsor tutorial](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/aspnetcore-facility.md)?

Comment: Thanks, I looked at it and tried to get it to work.   It does however indicate that it is unreleased.

Comment: In that case you can plug in your own `IControllerActivator` implementation, but note that that Facility uses the same approach. I would go with the official facility, even though it is still in beta.